# What is the meaning of this error: You are not connected to any peers. There is most likely some network issue. Fix connectivity

Tags: go-ethereum, parity, parity-wallet

I am getting following error in parity ui. how to fix it.

[image]

Comment: Could you please let us know what OS and what version of parity you are using? Is it a fresh install or an upgrade from a previous version? Did it work before and just stop working or didn't it work ever at all?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 16.

Comment: Any log output?

Answer (score 0):

This kind of problem has been seen several times before in different versions of the Parity software. Some sources report you may have to delete your nodes.js file, though some report that this fixes the problem only temporarily.